# Iam getting this error in R Program : Error in RobinHood::api_login(username, password, mfa_code) : Bad Request (HTTP 400)

Tags: r

Iam getting this error in R Program : Error in RobinHood::api_login(username, password, mfa_code) :    Bad Request (HTTP 400).

RH Credentials

> RH = RobinHood(username = "*****@gmail.com", password = "****")

Comment: Can you provide more of the code you're using? Any http error that starts with a 4 (e.g. 400) means that there's something wrong on your end (as opposed to the website's server). It may expect other arguments, or perhaps the login credentials were spelled incorrectly or something like that.

Comment: Just found [this](https://github.com/JestonBlu/RobinHood/issues/157) issue. I haven't used the package before, so am not fully across it, but you may have success if you try using a mfa token (something like `RobinHood(username, password, mfa_code = your_token)`). See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RobinHood/RobinHood.pdf#page=42).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.